# Create Windows Shortcut with Ruby, open in text editor

Tags: ruby, shortcut

I am using the win32 gem to create shortcut links to text files.

Mostly, it works, but I want to add a part so that I can click on the link and open up the file that it points to with a text editor (for example, Notepad).

The code runs without any apparent issues, but when I click on the link, nothing happens.

```
require 'win32/shortcut'
include Win32

def new_shortcut(args = {})
  folder1 = args[:folder1]
  folder2 = args[:folder2]

  shortcut_name = args[:shortcut_name]
  shortcut_description = args[:shortcut_description]
  file_ext = args[:file_ext]

  Shortcut.new("#{folder1}/#{shortcut_name}.lnk") do |s|
    s.description       = shortcut_description
    s.path              = folder2
    s.show_cmd          = Shortcut::SHOWNORMAL
    s.working_directory = folder1

     if file_ext == ".rb"
       s.path = Dir::WINDOWS << "\\notepad.exe"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Corrections to my post above:  That code actually doesn't work.  Dir::Windows is an uninitialized constant.

Comment: What if you add `require 'win32/dir'` ?  Looks like you need the `win32-dir` gem as well.

Comment: Thanks, that helped.  I no longer get the uninitialized constant error.  No the shortcut opens Notepad, but not the file.  I can't see a way to specify, open a given file with this application.

Comment: Well all you've done is specify a shortcut that points to `notepad.exe` You aren't using `folder2` anywhere when the type is `.rb`

Answer (score 0):

What if we fix the `path` portion by changing this line:

```
s.path = Dir::WINDOWS << "\\notepad.exe"
```

To either

```
s.path = "%WINDIR%/notepad.exe"
#or 
s.path = %x(echo %WINDIR%).chomp << "/notepad.exe"
```

`%WINDIR%` is the Windows environment variable for the windows directory so either one of these options should work for you without the need for an additional dependency.

Don't worry about the forward slashes the `win32-shortcut` gem is already handling those for you. Then you need to specify the actual file to open because you are overwriting `path` for these files so let's take it a step further

```
if file_ext == ".rb"
  s.path = "%WINDIR%/notepad.exe"
  s.arguments = folder2
end
```

This will cause the "Target" in the link to be "%WINDIR%\notepad.exe WHATEVER_FOLDER2_IS" which is the correct syntax for opening a file with note pad from a link.

So in summation I would write the method as (with a little cleanup)

```
def new_shortcut(args = {})
  folder1 = args[:folder1]
  folder2 = args[:folder2]

  shortcut_name = args[:shortcut_name]
  shortcut_description = args[:shortcut_description]
  # use `File` class to get the extension
  file_ext = File.extname(folder2)

  Shortcut.new("#{folder1}/#{shortcut_name}.lnk") do |s|
    s.description = shortcut_description

    s.show_cmd = Shortcut::SHOWNORMAL

    if file_ext == ".rb" 
      #set the working directory so no need to make it part of path
      s.working_directory = "%WINDIR%" 
      s.path = "notepad.exe"
      s.arguments = folder2 
    else
      s.path = folder2
    end
  end
end
```

Obviously this could use additional handling for missing name, and for things like directories that should probably use `explorer.exe`, other applications for other extensions, etc. but you get the idea.